# Why is my rating bar showing stars that are cutoff?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The stars keep getting cut off if I adjust the layout_width or layout_height - it also as issues even when I make it small or big.

I have tried adjusting or using: style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/MyRating"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="33.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/getRating"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="0.1"
            android:minHeight="18dp"
            android:maxHeight="18dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px">

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="71.0dp"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:max="5"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Indicator"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:scaleX="0.5"
            android:scaleY="0.5"
            tools:rating="3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12.5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Rating bar is a subclass of AbsSeekbar class, which is a subclass of ProgressBar. So it is built to always maintain an aspect ratio, and will cut off anything that isnt within the aspect ratio Set your layout_height="0dp", and then change your width as you like it's size to be.

Comment: @Jake, you said that RatingBar showing stars are cutoff, I try your code, and the first line is full of stars, the second line is only five stars, so you means that the second line RatingBar show stars are cutoff? I find you set android:numStars="5", so  If you use this attribute , you make sure RatingBar width is wrap content. so I think these two line should display 5 stars.

Comment: I found that adding padding to a Rating bar is way to get weird star filled in effects.  I did it and when I had a rating of 5/5 it would show 4 stars filled in half the 5th.  very odd.